# unrecognized token: "4eL2" c# SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, c#-4.0, exception

My problem is that I'm trying to store a image .tif in a sqlite database, I convert the image in base64String, but in the moment to execute the query give an exception

"SQL logic error or missing database
unrecognized token: "4eL2""

HERE is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Images\myimage.TIF");
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
byte [] b =  (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
SaveImage(base64String);

void SaveImage(string pic)
        {
            string query = "insert into mytable (date, imagen) values (2014, "+pic+");";
            string conString = @" Data Source = C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\images.sqlite3";
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(conString);
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);

            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException exc1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc1.Message);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm use this way:

```
void SaveImage(byte[] imagen)
        {
            string conStringDatosUsuarios = @" Data Source = C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\images.sqlite3";
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(conStringDatosUsuarios);
            SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO imagenes (date, imagen) VALUES ('01/01/2014', 'DIRIGIDO A QUIEN LE INTERESE', '2014', @0);");
            SQLiteParameter param = new SQLiteParameter("@0", System.Data.DbType.Binary);
            param.Value = imagen;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception exc1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc1.Message);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

In the .sqlite3 i put the column imagen with blob datatype

Answer (score 0):

Since `pic` is string data, you need to wrap it in quotes for your query:

```
string query = "insert into mytable (date, imagen) values (2014, '"+pic+"');";
```

Comment: Please use parameterized queries! This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = String.Format("insert into mytable (date, imagen) values ({0}, '{1}');", 2014, pic);
```

pic is a string, so it should be in single quotes(')